# How do I filter out SQL rows where numbers range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a login column that has the text FTO and then a sequence of numbers following it (i.e. `FTO3210` or `FTO1002`). I have a query that says `SELECT * FROM tablename`. I am trying to filter it so that it does not `SELECT` any row that has a login value ranging from `FTO1000` to `FTO1010`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FRM [Table] WHERE [Login] NOT BETWEEN 'FTO1000' AND 'FTO1010'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE CAST(REPLACE([Login],'FTO','') AS INT) NOT BETWEEN 1000 AND 1010
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1feced/6/0):

```
CREATE TABLE X ( 
  V VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
  );
INSERT X (V) VALUES ('FTO3210');
INSERT X (V) VALUES ('FTO1002');

SELECT V FROM X WHERE NOT SUBSTR(V,4,4) BETWEEN '1000' and '1010';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where login NOT BETWEEN 'FTO1000' AND 'FTO1010'
```